# How to efficiently read/parse loads of .gz files in a s3 folder with spark on EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I'm trying to read all files in a directory on s3 via a spark app that's executing on EMR.

The data is store in a typical format like "s3a://Some/path/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/blah.gz"

If I use deeply nested wildcards (e.g. "s3a://SomeBucket/SomeFolder/*/*/*/*/*.gz"), the performance is terrible and takes about 40 minutes to read a few tens of thousand small gzipped json files.
It works, but losing 40 minutes to test some code is really bad.

I have two other approaches that my research has told me are much more performant.

Using the hadoop.fs library (2.8.5) I try to read each file path I provide it.

```scala
private def getEventDataHadoop(
    eventsFilePaths: RDD[String]
  )(implicit sqlContext: SQLContext): Try[RDD[String]] =
    Try(
      {
        val conf = sqlContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration

        eventsFilePaths.map(eventsFilePath => {
          val p                            = new Path(eventsFilePath)
          val fs                           = p.getFileSystem(conf)
          val eventData: FSDataInputStream = fs.open(p)
          IOUtils.toString(eventData)
        })
      }
    )
```

These file paths are generated by the below code:

```scala
private[disneystreaming] def generateInputBucketPaths(
    s3Protocol: String,
    bucketName: String,
    service: String,
    region: String,
    yearsMonths: Map[String, Set[String]]
  ): Try[Set[String]] =
    Try(
      {
        val days                         = 1 to 31
        val hours                        = 0 to 23
        val dateFormatter: Int => String = buildDateFormat("00")

        yearsMonths.flatMap { yearMonth: (String, Set[String]) =>
          for {
            month: String <- yearMonth._2
            day: Int      <- days
            hour: Int     <- hours
          } yield
            s"$s3Protocol$bucketName/$service/$region/${dateFormatter(yearMonth._1.toInt)}/${dateFormatter(month.toInt)}/" +
              s"${dateFormatter(day)}/${dateFormatter(hour)}/*.gz"
        }.toSet
      }
    )
```

The hadoop.fs code fails because the Path class is not serializable. I can't think of how I can get around that.

So this led me to another approach using AmazonS3Client, where I just ask the client to give me all the file paths in a folder (or prefix), then parse the files to a string, which will likely fail due to them being compressed:

```scala
 private def getEventDataS3(bucketName: String, prefix: String)(
    implicit sqlContext: SQLContext
  ): Try[RDD[String]] =
    Try(
      {
        import com.amazonaws.services.s3._, model._
        import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

        val request = new ListObjectsRequest()
        request.setBucketName(bucketName)
        request.setPrefix(prefix)
        request.setMaxKeys(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        val s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default"))

        val objs: ObjectListing = s3.listObjects(request) // Note that this method returns truncated data if longer than the "pageLength" above. You might need to deal with that.
        sqlContext.sparkContext
          .parallelize(objs.getObjectSummaries.asScala.map(_.getKey).toList)
          .flatMap { key =>
            Source
              .fromInputStream(s3.getObject(bucketName, key).getObjectContent: InputStream)
              .getLines()
          }
      }
    )
```

This code produce a null exception because the profile cannot be null ("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null").
Remember this code is running on EMR within AWS, so how do I provide the credentials it wants? How are other people running spark jobs on EMR using this client?

Any help with getting any of these approaches working is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient()` to initialise the S3 connection.

Answer (score 0):

Path is serializable in later Hadoop releases, because it is useful to be able to use in Spark RDDs. Until then, convert the path to a URI, marshall that, and create a new path from that URI inside your closure.